# something like pivot table on postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as below:

car table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW |
| 2 | Volvo |
| 3 | Toyota |

option table:

| id | carid | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | airbag | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | seat | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | sunroof | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | airbag | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | seat | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | sunroof | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | airbag | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | seat | 5 |
| 9 | 3 | sunroof | 0 |

how can I create the below table:

| id | name | airbag | sunroof | seat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | Volvo | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | Toyota | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Comment: [Crosstab and pivot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use pivoting logic here:

```sql
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    MAX(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.name = 'airbag')  AS airbag,
    MAX(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.name = 'sunroof') AS sunroof,
    MAX(o.value) FILTER (WHERE o.name = 'seat')    AS seat
FROM car c
LEFT JOIN option o
    ON o.carid = c.id
GROUP BY
    c.id;
```

With the help of Postgres' support for the `FILTER` clause, the pivoting logic above becomes very terse and manageable.